# Yum won't resolve a lib dependency though it is available/installed?

Tags: centos, yum, xpra

I am trying to install xpra on CentOS 6.9.

Upon `yum install xpra`, I get:

```
Error: Package: xpra-1.0.12-2.r19800.el6_9.x86_64 (winswitch)
           Requires: libx264.so.148()(64bit)
           Available: x264-xpra-20170704-1.el6_9.x86_64 (winswitch)
               libx264.so.148()(64bit)
           Installing: x264-xpra-20190109-0.el6_9.x86_64 (winswitch)
               Not found
```

I downloaded the package `x264-xpra-20190109-0.el6_9.x86_64` manually and installed it using it `yum localinstall`

This results in the ollowing error on `yum install xpra`:

```
Error: Package: xpra-1.0.12-2.r19800.el6_9.x86_64 (winswitch)
           Requires: libx264.so.148()(64bit)
           Available: x264-xpra-20170704-1.el6_9.x86_64 (winswitch)
               libx264.so.148()(64bit)
           Installed: x264-xpra-20190109-0.el6_9.x86_64 (@/x264-xpra-20190109-0.el6_9.x86_64)
               Not found
```

I noticed that `/usr/lib64/xpra` only has `libx264.so.155`, therefore I tried locating a package online that has `libx264.so.148`.

That is `x264-xpra-20160704-1.sdl6.x86_64.rpm`. I installed it using `yum localinstall` again and verified that `libx264.so.148` was indeed present in `/usr/lib64/xpra`.

However, now upon trying to reinstall xpra, I get:

```
Error: Package: xpra-1.0.12-2.r19800.el6_9.x86_64 (winswitch)
           Requires: libx264.so.148()(64bit)
           Removing: x264-xpra-20160704-1.sdl6.x86_64 (@/x264-xpra-20160704-1.sdl6.x86_64)
               libx264.so.148()(64bit)
           Updated By: x264-xpra-20190109-0.el6_9.x86_64 (winswitch)
               Not found
           Available: x264-xpra-20170704-1.el6_9.x86_64 (winswitch)
               libx264.so.148()(64bit)
```

I'm quite lost, how can I proceed?

Comment: I looked at the RPM files, and it seems that the 'libx264.so.148' file is provided by the 2017 version of the package (x264-xpra-20170704-1.el6_9.x86_64). That package is also in the same repo. Perhaps `yum` found the new version of package, but found that it did not resolve the dependency, and hence failed? In any case, try installing this package locally and then see if the main installation works. You'll need to remove the two packages you've already installed.

Comment: Tried doing what you said, but got:
 
`Error: Package: xpra-1.0.12-2.r19800.el6_9.x86_64 (winswitch)
           Requires: libx264.so.148()(64bit)
           Removing: x264-xpra-20170704-1.el6_9.x86_64 (@/x264-xpra-20170704-1.el6_9.x86_64)
               libx264.so.148()(64bit)
           Updated By: x264-xpra-20190109-0.el6_9.x86_64 (winswitch)
               Not found
`

Comment: Thanks for the update. I think my assumption still holds here. '20190109' is the latest package in the repo, but it does not satisfy the dependency. That seems like a packaging error. If the number of dependencies isn't large, perhaps you can get them manually with `yumdownloader`, disconnect the xpra repo and then try to install. If `yum` is not able to the find the 20190109 package, it should proceed with the installation as expected.